# Only the background of div is hidden by img?

Tags: html, css

A div which contains an image has rounded corners using `border-radius` and `overflow:hidden`.

The div also contains another div with an orange background and some white text.

When the second div is placed over the image using a negative margin, the result is that the orange background is hidden behind the image, but the white text appears over top of the image.  Why is this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nq9Jv/

Further question: how do I make the orange div appear fully "above" the image, bearing in mind that I cannot use `position: relative` because that would take it out of the flow and thus not allow the border radius of the first div to conceal a part of the second.

Comment: @codehorse But I don't want to HIDE the text, I want to REVEAL the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure the reason that the orange background doesn't appear above the image when using a negative margin.

I have tweaked your example a bit, and by using `position: relative` on the parent element and `position: absolute` on the child element, made the orange div appear above the image while maintaining the `border-radius` concealing the child element.

http://jsfiddle.net/nq9Jv/4/

Is that what you want?

Comment: This is what I was trying to do from the start, yes.  For some reason it works in JSFiddle but not on my production site, as every time I add "position: relative" the "overflow:hidden" gets disabled for some reason.  But that is just debugging for me I guess.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. If you can reproduce the behavior in JSFiddle or send me a link to your production site, I'd be happy to take a look. Cheers!

Comment: Ended up being the fault of the browser.  A quick update and all was well!  Thanks!